# How to convert a string containing integers passed as command line arguements into an array of integers

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

./a.out "1 23 5 7 2 21"
I want to convert the above string passed as a command line argument into an array of integers in C programming. Would really appreciate help.

Thank you.

Comment: "_I have tried a lot of methods but none is working._" -- Please show us.

Comment: a little magic of `strtok()` and `atoi()`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop can solve your problem-

```
int a[argc];

for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
{
      a[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Sorry I didn't get you .

Answer (score 0):

## If passing a string

**./a.out "1 23 5 7 2 21"**

You need to tokenize the string whilst passing the "int" value to an array (which should be dynamic) since you are passing a *string* and not multiple options. (Which was what I initially thought, but changed)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> /* For strtok */


int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
   int i = 0;
   int *intArray;
   const char s[2] = " ";
   char *token;

   token = strtok(argv[1], s);

   intArray = malloc(sizeof(int));
   while( token != NULL )
   {
      intArray[i++] = atoi(token);
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

    //intArray holds the values but this is to display the results
    int j;
    for (j=0; j < i ; j++){
        printf( " %d\n", intArray[j] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## If passing multiple options (after program name)

**./a.out 1 23 5 7 2 21**

```
    int i;
    int intArray[argc-1];
    for (i=0; i < argc - 1; i++){
        intArray[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
    }
    return 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int n = 0;//number of elements
    char prev = ' ', *s = argv[1];
    while(*s){
        if(isspace(prev) && !isspace(*s))
            ++n;
        prev = *s++;
    }
    int nums[n];
    char *endp;
    s = argv[1];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        nums[i] = strtol(s, &endp, 10);
        s = endp;
        printf("%d\n", nums[i]);//check print
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could use `int n = 0; for(n = 0; ; ++n){ strtol(s, &endp, 10); s = endp; }` to calculate `n` to parse _exactly_ the same as the 2nd pass.